# Best way to separate a big dependency from my WAR file

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jasper-reports, war

I am trying to incorporate JasperReports into an existing Java web project. After managing to get everything to work I found out that my WAR file had grown to quite a scary filesize (> 25MB) because of all of the dependencies. With some tinkering I managed to bring it down to 16MB.

I would like to avoid this huge amount of dependencies. For reasons of  filesize, but also because I am slightly worried about the versions of JasperReport's dependencies. JasperReports seems to depend on older versions of many of its dependencies. I'm afraid that at some point this will cause compatibility problems with the rest of my application.

For the moment I have solved this by deploying a separate WAR file that just generates the reports. The original web app communicates with this new one by using Tomcat's `crossContext="true"` parameter. The two app's servlets communicate by passing a series of attributes using `request.setAttribute(arg)`. The file size might still be there, but at least it's inside of a WAR that I'll hardly touch.

The actual question should probably be something along the lines of: How can I separate JasperReports (or in fact any other big library) from my web app without using the servlet container's common classloader?

Also: am I being overly cautious here?